# How to save a UIImage to Parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform, uiimage

I've taken an image and converted it to the jpeg format as such

```
let jpgImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1, 0.5)
```

Next I want to upload this image to Parse as a object part of a PFUser. When ever I try this I get the error

```
[Error]: The object is too large -- should be less than 128 kB
```

I don't know how to fix this error and just sign up the user. Thanks for any help or advice!

Comment: As stated in the error, the image is too large. Images should be stored separately from PFUser object, and then loaded asynchronously any time you need them.

Comment: This is what PFFile is for.  Create one, assign arbitrarily large data to it, save it, then place the PFFile (just a reference to the data) in any object as a file-type property.

Comment: Post all of your code. Save this as a PFFile. If you post your code I am pretty sure I can answer this.

Comment: so you think i should make another object called a userimage and save a PFFile with the username there and then just query when i need it?

Comment: it seems annoying because then i have to keep on passing the imgae around from screen to screen because it's not part of the PFUser.currentUser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects are limited to 128kb as the error states, if your image is larger than that as it is you can choose to shrink it by using the function below.

```
func ResizeImage(image: UIImage, targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let size = image.size
    let widthRatio  = targetSize.width  / image.size.width
    let heightRatio = targetSize.height / image.size.height
    // Figure out what our orientation is, and use that to form the rectangle
    var newSize: CGSize
    if(widthRatio > heightRatio) {
        newSize = CGSizeMake(size.width * heightRatio, size.height * heightRatio)
    } else {
        newSize = CGSizeMake(size.width * widthRatio,  size.height * widthRatio)
    }

    // This is the rect that we've calculated out and this is what is actually used below
    let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)

    // Actually do the resizing to the rect using the ImageContext stuff
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
    image.drawInRect(rect)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}
```

Use of the above function, you can resize your image as dynamics 
dimension.Here as above code resize image of 200*200. By calling the 
below function.

```
self.ResizeImage(UIImage(named: "yourImageName")!, targetSize: CGSizeMake(200.0, 200.0))
```

Source code from [here](http://iosdevcenters.blogspot.in/2015/12/how-to-resize-image-in-swift-in-ios.html).

So start by checking the image size by:

```
let sizeOfImage = image?.size

if let image = image {
    let sizeOfImage = image.size
    // Check the size here and resize if needed
}
```